# App crashes while printing array after free()

Tags: c, malloc

Why does it crash while trying to `printf()` after having `free()`?

I've created dyanmic array. Displayed elements. Filled each elements with value. Then freed memory using `free()`. And then trying to display elements again.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *p;

    p = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        printf("%d  ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        p[i] = i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");


    free(p);
    p = NULL;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )  /* App crashes around here. */
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I'm new to **C**.

Let me know what is wrong, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you reference memory pointing to `NULL`.

This is actually *undefined behavior* so it *might* work, but dereferencing a `NULL` pointer most likely will cause a crash.

---

Even if you don't set the pointer to `NULL` it's still undefined behavior to derreference unallocated memory, and although it most likely won't crash it's still a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

When you `free` any memory, its gone. You can not use it any more.

You should `free` the after you are done with it.

You are using the pointer `p` after you have freed it. The system assumes you do not need the memory once you free it. So it does not reserve it for you. It may work some times if the memory is still unused. But in this case you are assigning `NULL` to the pointer `p` and then trying to print the value present there, which is definitely not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

One thing always to be remembered.. A freed memory can return the expected result (it sometimes does). Me too sometimes suffered with the problem.. U can finde useful insight here:

[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Now come to your code:

```
free(p);
```

Here you may get your expected things..but u r not guaranteed and r not permitted to use this. It is undefined behaviour. But now

```
p = NULL;
```

is something that is crashing your program. Because the pointer now points to NULL, and it is not permitted to de-reference a NULL pointer.  Do not point to NULL if you don't actually need it. And never ever de-reference a NULL pointer.